# VBA Excel Backup: Save copy of current workbook via VBA under a new name, keep VBA scripts, no prompt

Tags: vba, excel, backup

I need to make a VBA script that can take a complete copy of the current workbook and save it under a new name.

It need to be a complete copy with VBA scripts and everything.

The user may NOT be prompted for anything - the new file name (and location) will be provided by the code.

Comment: `.SaveCopyAs`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx

Comment: It's very easy and is fully supported by Excel Macro Recorder. Remember to use Save as and set file extension to '.xlsm'...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely something like this is sufficient?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: When combining @Siddharth Rout and roger_rowland i got a working code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that at least for Excel 2013 `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data.xlsm` may not work as on my end it is saying that excel cannot save as file type xlsm.

[image]

However I did find a work around that is working for myself and wanted to add it here as a reference for others who may run into the same problem.

If you add `, FileFormat:=52` after your code it will be able to save as the `xlsm` format.

So this worked for me:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data.xlsm, FileFormat:=52"
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Activeworkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Data.xlsm"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.